# Oracle APEX dynamically delete the filters in saved reports

Tags: oracle, filter, oracle-apex

I have an IR, which has some saved reports and what I need to perform is, delete the filters that are bound to the saved reports because I need to dynamically change the filter values.
So far, I have the query to get all the saved private reports as follows.

```
SELECT  a.flow_id,a.page_id,a.status,a.application_user,a.name,        b.interactive_report_id, c.condition_type,c.column_name,c.operator,c.expr
FROM apex_040000.wwv_flow_worksheet_rpts a, apex_application_page_ir b,  apex_040000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_CONDITIONS c
WHERE a.flow_id = :APP_ID
AND a.page_id = b.page_id
AND b.application_id = a.flow_id
AND a.worksheet_id = b.interactive_report_id
AND a.status = 'PRIVATE'
AND c.report_id = a.id
AND c.column_name='YEAR'
and a.page_id= :APP_PAGE_ID
```

Please give me your ideas.